# Publish MS-Project Add-In to Microsoft Store?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, ms-project

In Microsoft Project 2016.
To see a list of published Microsoft Store Project Add-Ins: Project Tab, Get Add Ins, Store, Project Management. Workday Projects Integration is an example of a published App.
What is the Visual Studio development and publishing path and is there a reliable, current template/tutorial etc?
thank you
Stew

[Image showing MS-Project Add-ns chosed from MS Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QztLR.jpg)

Comment: See [Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center).